# List.stream().filter() vs removeIf

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Please help me understand the difference.

I'm trying to remove elements from list. If I use stream().filter(), this works but when I use removeIf, it throws UnsupportedOperationException.

```
private void filterEmployees(EmployeeResponse employeeResponse) {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeResponse.getEmployees();
        List<Employee> employeesFiltered = employees
                .stream()
                .filter(employee -> employee.getRole().equals("01") || employee.getRole().equals("02") || employee.getRole().equals("03"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        employeeResponse.setEmployees(employeesFiltered);
    }
```

Below code throws UnsupportedOperationException.

```
private void filterEmployees(EmployeeResponse employeeResponse, List<String> rolesList) {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeResponse.getEmployees();
        employees.removeIf(employee -> !rolesList.contains(employee.getRole()));
        employeeResponse.setEmployees(employees);
    }
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: remove

    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.remove(Iterator.java:102)
    at java.base/java.util.Collection.removeIf(Collection.java:545)
```

Comment: The stacktrace of the exception would ideally convey why is the operation not supported. Mostly, you have an immutable or unmodifiable `Collection` returned from `employeeResponse.getEmployees()` which would not allow removal via `removeIf`. Note, that with `filter` you are creating a new List and assigning it back instead of updating the exisitng.

Comment: *"The stacktrace of the exception would ideally convey why is the operation not supported."* -  It definitely will, if you know how to read it.  It is a pity that the OP didn't show it to us.

Comment: @StephenC Added the exception and the employees list is not a immutable object

Comment: OK so the stacktrace doesn't tell us.  (But it doesn't say it is not immutable either.)  What is the actual list class?

Comment: As I commented below the problem may be Arrays.asList.  its size can't be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming list with a filter simply filters the current list, skipping the unwanted values, and creates a new one.  I would be equivalent to you iterating the list and when you see the value, skip it. Otherwise add it to the new list.

`removeIf` is a new method in Java 8.  It is in the `Collections` interface which `List` extends.  That method is not supported in any immutable collection or in `List.of` which creates an `ImmutableCollection`.

I can't tell if that is the problem so you may want to check if that instance is immutable by doing the following:

```
List<Employee> employees = employeeResponse.getEmployees();
System.out.println(employees.getClass().getName());
```

One way to possibly solve that problem is to do the following:

```
List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>(employeeResponse.getEmployees());
```

Which creates a mutable `ArrayList` and populates it with the employee list.  Then `removeIf` should work as expected.

Comment: I tried this `System.out.println(employees.getClass().getName());` and it gave me `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`

Comment: Look at the documentation for `Arrays.asList`.  The list it returns will throw an unsupported operation exception for any method that would modify the size.  That could be the problem. Try the option I gave you to create a new modifiable list.